# Gas price is reverted to be zero after updating using REST API on a Kaleido node

Tags: gas-price, kaleido

For those who have used Kaleido nod
I'm running a PoA node on Kaleido and I want to set the minimal gas price for the node.

I followed the instruction below to update a node configuration using REST API.

- https://docs.kaleido.io/using-kaleido/blockchain-advanced-configuration/#gas-price

After updating, I attached to the node and checked eth.gasPrice on the geth console and I could confirm eth.gasPrice is updated from zero (which is default) but a few minutes later, it reverts to zero AUTOMATICALLY.

I could not find the answer to why this happens so it'd be very appreciated if you can help me.